# python TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'list'

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV containing 28 UUIDs

I would like to create a  python loop which runs each uuid individually and places it into a filepath

e.g. `Org/datasets/uuid/data`

I have tried the below but failing

```
import os
import csv

uuid = []
with open('C:/Users/Public/file.csv', 'r') as file:
  reader = csv.reader(file)
  for row in reader:
    uuid.append(row)

for i in uuid:
  filepath = os.path.join("org/datasets/",  i , "/data")
  print(filepath)
```

error is `TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'list'`

The CSV is very simplistic and looks as follows:

| uuid | blank |
| --- | --- |
| uuid1 | blank |
| uuid2 | blank |

Comment: In the code given, `uuid` is a list of lists. You need to select the item you want out of each row of the input file (each row is given to you as a list due to using `csv.reader`) and store that one.

Comment: How do I create a loop that will place the uuid in the filepath like I've shown by extracting the uuid from the CSV?

Comment: What does your CSV file look like? No one can give you a real answer without knowing what `uuid` holds

Comment: @BTables see edited code. The CSV only contains the uuids

Comment: In which case you want `uuid.append(row[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your for loop ever value of `i` corresponds to a row in your csv file. As such, it comes out as a list, something you cannot concat against a str. Instead, you should be taking the first element of your list(the actual uuid)

```
for i in uuid:
  filepath = os.path.join("org/datasets/",  i[0] , "/data")
  print(filepath)
```

Comment: I ha to use ```+``` rather than ```,```  but other than that, this worked - thanks!

Comment: If you're directly appending the strings together then you can just drop the `os.path.join` as it's no longer doing anything.

Answer (score 2):

I've experienced a similar issue for data science training:
When you train a model from a dataset in CSV,
any empty lines will triggers errors because NaN is of type float, not str.

So in my case the dataset was the culprit: I've had to remove the empty lines that were not cleaned

Answer (score 0):

#Try this code:

```
import os
import csv
uuid = []
with open('C:/Users/Public/file.csv', 'r') as file:
   reader = CSV.reader(file)  
   for row in reader:
      uuid.append(row[0])

for i in uuid:
   filepath = os.path.join("org/datasets/",  i , "/data")
   print(filepath)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).